# How to retrieve a board background color or image in Manatee.Trello?

Tags: c#, manatee.trello

I am trying to retrieve an existing board background color or image using Manatee.Trello. Here is what I've tried so far :

```
Board myboard =  new Search(SearchFor.TextInName("MyAwesomeBoard"), 1, SearchModelType.Boards).Boards.FirstOrDefault();
var boardColor = myboard.Preferences.Background.Color;
var boardImg = myboard.Preferences.Background.Image;
```

According to the accessors signatures, this should return either a `string` or a `WebColor`.
It compiles fine, but at runtime I get the following error :

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Even though the board currently has an image or color background. Is there another way to access this info or is there a bug in Manatee.Trello ?

Comment: There might be a bug.  I'll run a test and come back.

Comment: It looks like you've found a bug!  I've logged an [issue](https://github.com/gregsdennis/Manatee.Trello/issues/68) for you in the Github repo.  Once resolved, I'll come back and answer.  For now, if you can get the board ID (the `nC8QJJoZ` in `https://trello.com/b/nC8QJJoZ/trello-development-roadmap`), you can use the `Board` constructor as a workaround.

Comment: @gregsdennis Thanks for the workaround ! For the moment, I use `new Board(new Search(SearchFor.TextInName(name), 1, SearchModelType.Boards).Boards.FirstOrDefault().Id)` to create my board and it works just fine. I've also followed the issue on github to be updated when the fix is live

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of hard-coding or configuring the ID, but that works, too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the search and will be resolved in the next release.  I've created [issue 68](https://github.com/gregsdennis/Manatee.Trello/issues/68) to track it.

### Update

Please see version 1.17.0 for the fix.